# Crawling through data in JS block in PHP

Tags: php

I want to find data from a webpage which stores data in Java Script block and later renders the page using those data. How to fetch such data in PHP ?
I've tried DOMXPath and DomDocument, still no luck !
Below I'm posting an example of the target page.

```
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
var showHeader = true;
var Data = {
  "packageId": "120",
  "packageTitle": "West Bengal",
  "Type": "Customizable",
   "Components": [
    {
      "destination": "Darjeeling",
      "dayNum": {
        "1": {
          "sightseeings": [
            "No Sightseeing"
          ],
          "itineraries": {
            "title": "Bagdogra / New Jalpaiguri - Darjeeling",
            "description": "<p>Welcome to darjeeling.</p>"
          }
        }
        }
      }
    ]
    };
</script>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I want to retrieve all those data in an associative array using PHP so I can use like **$data['showHeader']** or **$data['data']['packageId']**

Comment: "I've tried DOMXPath and DomDocument" and yet no code provided in the question?

Answer (score -1):

How about to extract the necessary data using a regular expression and convert it to array as follows:

```
if (preg_match('#^var showHeader = (?P<showHeader>\w+);\s*^var Data = (?P<json>{.*?});#ms', $html, $m)) {
    $data = [
        'showHeader' => ($m['showHeader'] === 'true' || $m['showHeader'] === '1'),
        'data' => json_decode($m['json'], true)
    ];

    echo $data['data']['packageId'];
} else {
    echo 'js data not found';
}
```

If there are several scripts, you may want to analyze contents of all scripts:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$data = [];
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script) {
    if (preg_match('#^var showHeader = (?P<showHeader>\w+);\s*^var Data = (?P<json>{.*?});#ms', $script->nodeValue, $m)) {
        $data['showHeader'] = ($m['showHeader'] === 'true' || $m['showHeader'] === '1');
        $data['data'] = json_decode($m['json'], true);
        break;
    }
}

if ($data) {
    echo $data['showHeader']['packageId'];
} else {
    echo 'js data not found';
}
```